# Remove Server from HTTP Response in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-7.5

I have an internet exposed WCF service running on IIS 7.5 that I need to secure.
I would like to remove the "Server" header in the HTTP response.

I've implemented an IDispatchMessageInspector with code as follows.

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    var context = WebOperationContext.Current;
    if (context != null)
    {
        context.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Remove(
            HttpResponseHeader.Server);
    }
}
```

However, the Server header is still in the response.
On debugging I can see that the `OutgoingResponse.Headers` does not include `HttpResonseHead.Server`, and if I write my own value it is clearly being overriten by something further down the line in the IIS pipeline.

**Edit 1**

Tried the following, no good either

```
public class SecureServerHeaderModule : IHttpModule
{
    #region Implementation of IHttpModule

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += OnPreSendRequestHeaders;
    }

    public void Dispose() { }

    #endregion

    private static void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");                
        }
    }
}

<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add "snip" />
  </httpModlules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add "snip" />
  </modlules>
</system.webServer>
```

**Edit 2**

Also did not work.

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    var context = OperationContext.Current;
    if (context != null)
    {
        context.OutgoingMessageProperties.Remove(
            HttpResponseHeader.Server.ToString());
        context.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(
            HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl.ToString(), "no-store");
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems @Trey Combs provided you with a working answer, but maybe you missed a service definition or two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works using an `IDispatchMessageInspector`

```
public class SecureBehaviour : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request,
        IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

        var httpCtx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpCtx != null)
        {
            httpCtx.Response.Headers.Remove(
                HttpResponseHeader.Server.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Microsoft for the actual answer

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried editing your web.config and using the [customHeaders](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders) tag under [system.webServer](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Server" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <remove name="X-AspNet-Version" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This results in my C# ASP.NET application only having the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, public
Content-Length: 20992
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 May 2012 18:01:11 GMT
ETag: "HHktEL5IWA6rspl4Bg2ZxNmnV3gTUCLt2cTldSsl05A="
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2012 21:38:38 GMT
```

Although I will admit I have not tried it with the "Server" header, this approach seems to work well.  The reason I have not tried it with the "Server" header is that the following code in my IHttpModule works just fine.

```
    void PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        if(HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline)
        {
            application.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
            application.Response.Headers.Remove("Expires");
            application.Response.Headers.Remove("Cache-Control");
            application.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600, public");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check a static file request headers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hosting your service in IIS and have an HttpModule already spun up, try setting the ASP.NET Compatibility mode so that you can get to HttpContext.Current.  You will need to make the following changes:

Modify your web.config and add the following to System.ServiceModel

```
<system.serviceModel>
  ...
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Decorate your service class with this attribute:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

Give the HttpModule another shot and you should have better luck.

Comment: That throws an exception System.InvalidOperationException: The service cannot be activated because it does not support ASP.NET compatibility. ASP.NET compatibility is enabled for this application. Turn off ASP.NET compatibility mode in the web.config or add the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service type with RequirementsMode setting as 'Allowed' or 'Required'.

Comment: The only way I can reproduce the error you described above is to make a service call to a service that has not been decorated with the "[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements...]" attribute.  Is there a service call being made to a service that is missing this attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the registry? If so you could try

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader
```

Comment: PS definitely not an HttpModule, when I am going through WCF the HttpContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 0):

Work in progress.

This [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx) answers a little more about the different pipelines and why ASP.NET modules aren't quite working.

More to follow.

Answer (score 0):

For my self-hosted WCF service the answer from M Afifi does not work. I have to set an empty header:

```
httpCtx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.Server.ToString(), string.Empty);
```

This removes the header from the response:

```
access-control-allow-headers →Content-Type, Authorization, Accept
access-control-allow-methods →GET, POST
access-control-allow-origin →*
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Mon, 03 Jul 2017 07:22:17 GMT
status →200
```