# Reading a SOAP response with bad HTTP header

Tags: vb.net, wcf, http, soap, wsdl

I am using a SOAP interface that is developed by a 3rd party, but is returning an invalid HTTP header as shown below.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK  
Server: SMBDK_1/2.3.0  
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 18:59:14 GMT  
Connection: close  
Content-Length: 670  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1  
Content-Type: text/xml  
Expires: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 18:59:14 GMT  
Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 18:59:14 GMT
```

Notice that there are 2 content-type tags. I am using VS2008 for this VB project.  I have a service reference for this connection and can send a request and receive a response.  I created a CustomTextMessageEncoder using the MSDN samples to read the response for `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`. This is working for single variable returns, but arrays are never read in correctly.  They are always empty.  I am using a Web Debugging Proxy and can see that the array information is there in the SOAP response, but it is never actually pulled through.  I presume this is due to the bad header (?). I tried decoding the message as `text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1` and got the same results... empty array returns.

Does anyone have any advice on how to handle this situation?   Do I need to deserialize this message manually or is there a better way?

Comment: Surely the right thing to do is to get the third party to fix their bug. The HTTP standard has been around for a while: what's their excuse for not following such a basic standard? And, ask yourself - if they can't even do HTTP right, what _else_ are they screwing up?

Comment: The last version of their software responded in text/xml; utf-8 encoding and everything worked great. I think someone on their end decided to upgrade, change the encoding, etc etc.  Unfortunately I have to connect to this service and get it working again on their new system.  Now I guess I am faced with quietly waiting for them to release a fix for this bug, or fight my way around it to still get the info I need.

Comment: text/xml sounds like SOAP 1.1, BTW. Also, do you actually have to be _quiet_? Their developers would probably like to know they have a bug.

Comment: I have communicated the issue to the developer and am waiting to hear back on a response / timeframe / fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, these bad headers prevented Visual Studio from ever reading in array's properly.
I wound up having to capture the entire response in an XMl document in memory then open it up and use xmlNodeList to manually read the data from the arrays.

Comment: You could've perhaps [removed on of the offending headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455273/remove-server-from-http-response-in-wcf), but then which one should you assume to be correct?