# Remove server response header at self hosted WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I know that there are a quite some posts online about removing the server header at http response, however, mostly I found out they are for IIS hosted WCF service. My application is hosting the WCF service. The object is ServiceHost, I added a behavior to the ServiceHost

```
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(ModifyResponseBehavior);
```

In the behavior,

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    var httpCtx = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current;
    if (httpCtx != null)
    {
        httpCtx.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Server", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

I tried add empty server value, and remove server headers, neither of them remove the server header at response.
Will any of you have a suggestion about this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible dublicate  [Remove Server from HTTP Response in WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455273/remove-server-from-http-response-in-wcf)

Comment: Thank you for pointing the post. Yeah, I did go through the post. However, his application is hosted on IIS, and he has access to HttpContext.Current, in my case, the HttpContext.Current is null.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i could remove it for my self-hosted service is set in Windows registry: 
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\DisableServerHeader = 2 

Restart the machine after the change and this will remove the Server header for all self-hosted services on that machine.